Firebase authentication with email link signin gives INVALID_OOB_CODE on dev ENV but works on local
While using signInWithEmail API of firebase auth on web, it working fine on local but when i deploy it. It just gives invalid code error
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "INVALID_OOB_CODE", "errors": [ { "message": "INVALID_OOB_CODE", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid" } ] } }
My configuration for email link login(actionCodeSettings)
EMAIL_LINK_DATA: { url: 'https://tinyview-dev.firebaseapp.com/verify-email', handleCodeInApp: true, iOS: { bundleId: 'com.newput.tinyview' }, android: { packageName: 'com.newput.tinyviewdev', installApp: true }, dynamicLinkDomain: 'tinyviewdev.page.link' }
I have also make sure that re-rendering is not causing this issue.
For further experience, you can try signup here and then do the signIn in which i am facing this issue.
